# What does an httppost return by default?

Tags: c#

I'm currently working with a number of third parties, sending them data via an HttpPost with an encrypted url string. Each of the third parties sends back an xml string which I then read and use. All is good!

The question I have is this. If I send a request to a third party, and they do not provide a response, what happens? To clarify, I mean that a response string isn't returned in all cases - not just errors and timeouts.

Comment: Do you mean response or response body? If you want to know why they don't send a response body, ask them. We can't possibly know.

Comment: @CodeCaster - No, I mean that they intentionally don't send a response back due to whatever reasons. What I'm asking is what does my httppost see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP protocol does not include a way to *not* send a response. A response is *always* sent. It might be zero length, though.

> I mean that a response string isn't returned in all cases

Is this a question or an assertion? This statement is false.

> and they do not provide a response, what happens?

So what happens in case of a zero-length response? That depends entirely on your code. Neither protocol not framework care about this case.

> Couldn't the socket actually be closed before any headers are sent back? Or, if the server is down?

That's a protocol violation. That's not HTTP, then. In such a situation the app is generally notified through an exception.

Comment: Couldn't the socket actually be closed before any headers are sent back? Or, if the server is down?

Comment: @Groo that's a protocol violation. That's not HTTP, then. Will result in an exception.

Comment: I don't know if it should technically be considered as HTTP, but I am pretty sure that OP is interested in real life scenarios. *If I send a request to a third party [and] a response string isn't returned in all cases* - how is that "not possible"?

Comment: @Groo, being a chrome user, I'm familiar with the error: `The server closed the connection without sending any data: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. So, that will result in an exception in c# too.

Comment: @Mathew: I agree, an exception is obviously thrown. That's why the answer seems a bit misleading ("A response is *always* sent").

Comment: @Groo this sentence is in the context of HTTP. In a valid HTTP conversation the response is always sent. If not, it is not valid HTTP and the app is generally notified through an exception. I don't really get your point but I added another remark. (It's pretty obvious that his code has a bug but he did not post it and did not ask about it.)

Answer (score 2):

Few things can happen:

- **A response is sent by the third party**: It consists of the desired output (an XML string in your case.
- **A response is sent, but the *content* is 0 length**: Take it into mind that HTTP response consists of two parts: HTTP headers, and content. In this case third party sends only the headers. You can consider this as `String.Empty` output.
- **A response is not sent**: Third part should have sent a response according to the HTTP protocol, but they don't. Third party may close the socket or just timeout. That can happen because of an internal problem, or they are just choosing not to respond to you. This will *normally* result in an exception. What the exception is, though, depends on the methods/library you use to send HTTP requests.